# How to convert type bool to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Tags: c#

How can I convert `bool` to `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`?

```
txtDirectory = chkSubfolders.Checked;
```

My error is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: It's telling you that you can't. So you can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Even if someone answered your question here, that is not going to help you in anyway.

Comment: LOL, no one really answered this question "How to convert type bool to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"...I found it too hard to explain..

Answer (score 4):

uhmm... That doesn't make sense?

A bool is a yes/no value, a TextBox is a full control with tons of properties.

Do you want to display the Value of the bool inside an existing textbox? In that case:

```
txtDirectory.Text = chkSubfolders.Checked.ToString();
```

But need more info what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to enable/disable the textbox on the basis of the Checked status

`txtDirectory.Enabled = chkSubfolders.Checked;`

OR

`txtDirectory.ReadOnly = chkSubfolders.Checked;`

If not *please edit and append what you really want to do*

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a bool to a textbox. You can convert the value of a bool and put it into the text of a textbox.

```
mytextbox.Text = myboolValue.Checked.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't.
You cannot assign a bool to a TextBox!!
If you want to write *true* or *false* in textbox you can do

```
txtDirectory.Text = chkSubfolders.Checked.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you can never convert `bool` to `TextBox`. I think what you need to achieve is

```
txtDirectory.Text = chkSubfolders.Checked.ToString();
```